# How to revert my git repository to the exact same state it was in disk, say, a month ago *without keeping secret new/recent content under the hood*?

Tags: git, github, git-rewrite-history

I tried `git reset --hard 0845f5de`, pushed to a new repository in github, but everything appears the same in the github stats like, e.g. number of commits.
Where is this information stored?

None of these incantations seem to make a difference:

```
7530  git update-ref -d refs/original/refs/heads/master
7531  git reflog expire --expire-unreachable=all --all
7532  git gc --prune=all
7534  git filter-branch master
7541  git gc --aggressive --prune=now
7545  git -c gc.reflogExpire=0 -c gc.reflogExpireUnreachable=0   -c gc.rerereresolved=0 -c gc.rerereunresolved=0   -c gc.pruneExpire=now gc "$@"
7547  rm -rf .git/refs/original/ .git/refs/remotes/ .git/*_HEAD .git/logs/
7548  git for-each-ref --format="%(refname)" refs/original/ |   xargs -n1 --no-run-if-empty git update-ref -d
7554  git reflog expire --all --expire=now
7555  git repack -A -d -f
7556  git gc --aggressive --prune=now
7558  git filter-branch --index-filter 'git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch Filenamexxxxxx' --prune-empty -- --all
```

*I am seriously thinking about recovering a pendrive backed up repository from a year ago and somehow replay the commits from the current repository until the last desired commit.*

Comment: If you have published commits to someone else, there's no guaranteed way to take them back, ever. However, if your GitHub repository is private, you can have the GitHub support folks expire commits and be reasonably sure nobody but GitHub have the deleted commits. If you don't have them take special action, the deletion will probably eventually happen, but if anyone else forked your repo, those commits will still be out there.

Comment: @torek Yes it is private. There is no one else accessing it, and the remote can be (and was) recreated at will, so I cannot understand why would be there any cache on the github side. The info used in stats seems to be in my local repository, no matter how I try to purge it.  I just want to keep the history until a certain point in time, like nothing (really nothing) happened after that.

Comment: I don't work for GitHub but I understand that those stats are generated every day or so: there's an assumption that you'll *add* commits but never *remove* them, so there's a base set from a day ago (or whenever) plus a database of "count of things to add to make it look like we have a live count". If you crank a repository back to zero, you get stale data.